# Form data not saving in databse in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a test from which needs to be save in database. 
When I submit the form it does not save anything in database. If anyone can review my code and check what's wrong inside the code that's stopping the form to save in database.

```
**Model**
class test(models.Model):
    testname = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50, help_text='Co-worker name.', default='')
    testPicture = models.ImageField('Co-Worker Picture', upload_to='../media/images/co-woker-pictures'
                                    , help_text='Co-worker Picture.', default='', null=True, blank=True)
    joiningDate = models.DateField('Joining Date', help_text='Joining Date of Co-worker',
                                   default=datetime.date.today, )

**form**
class testForm(forms.ModelForm):
    testname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
    }))
    testPicture = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
    }))
    joiningDate = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
        'id': 'datePicker',
    }))

    class Meta:
        model = test
        fields = ['testname', 'testPicture', 'joiningDate']

**view**
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = testForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            u = form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'test successful.')
            return redirect('test', )
    else:
        form = testForm()

    c = context = ({
    'form': form,
    })
    return render(request, 'test.html', c)
```

Comment: can you also provide the template of the form ?

Comment: also it's best to print an `else` statement on form.is_valid() so you can see what causing the form to fail

Comment: In case of submitting a document or other image or any file then use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in a form tag in template